# Python/Selenium can't get title of youtube video after search

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, visual-studio-code, selenium-chromedriver

I'm learning how to use selenium and I want to make a program that opens up youtube, searches for a video and prints the title of the first video to appear. I don't know why but it instead prints the title of the first video on youtube's homepage.

```
from logging import exception
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

PATH = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")

search = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input#search')
search.send_keys("busqueda")
time.sleep(1)
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(5)
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="video-title"]')))

    print("título: ", element.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
except BaseException as e:
    print(e)            
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below xpath, which will print the YouTube videos title with,
`'.//a[@class = "yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-video-renderer"]//yt-formatted-string[@class = "style-scope ytd-video-renderer"]'`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
elem=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a#video-title yt-formatted-string.style-scope.ytd-video-renderer")
print(elem.text)
```

Should suffice for the first element with that selector. After you add a wait.